SQL Server Data Tools SSIS Delay Notification
I was working on a project using SQL Server Data Tools, and I don't know what happened exactly since I didn't perform any stupid things as I can remember, but it keeps freezing and open a dialog that says Visual Studio is busy and unable to respond at this time.
I tried the two options in the screenshot, and both Switch to... and Continue Waiting results in opening the same dialog again as if I'm on a loop. Anyone please help, I'm struggling with this.
Thanks in advance.

